# How to load sites from your own server as localhost (ssh tunnel trickery)

Tags: ssh, security

I want to load a site from my server as if I'm on the server as localhost. Because some areas are restricted to localhost on a purpose.

Now normal ssh tunnel like ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 username@server.com 
will let me type localhost:8080 in the browser on my PC but that will load just the server IP as if I'm there.
I wan to load a specific site (one of many) on that server.
They are not accessible by server-ip/domain.com either

so i need way to tell my server load one of it's own sites from localhost and send it to me over ssh if we have to sum it up :)

Comment: Doesn't sound like a reasonable setup to me. For exposing an internal host via an encrypted channel, mod_proxy (see SSLProxyEngine) should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you're using Virtualhosts on your server, and you need to send a domain name with the requests, so that specific sites are presented.

If thats the case, then add an entry in your hosts file like so:

```
127.0.0.1 www.somesite.com
```

You can then access it on your local pc with

```
http://www.somesite.com:8080/blah
```

Comment: Yes virtual hosts on the server site for many sites. The server IP alone doesn't load anything.
If you mean to load the hosts entry on the local PC that would just make it so when this site is entered on the PC to load the server IP. No good.
If you mean to add this hosts records on the server side shouldn't i access it typing localhost:8080 on the local PC which would redirect to the server IP by the SSH tunnel, which would load the site? Will it work like that and is there any disadvantage at the server side for that?

Comment: The host entries go on the client. Then your browser will send an http(s) request with the host header set to the correct domain. The webserver can then serve the correct content. I had assumed you only wanted this for testing purposes. If thats not the case, then an ssh tunnel simply should not be involved.